# Twitter Bootstrap carousel: event scope?

Tags: events, twitter-bootstrap, scope, carousel

I have a Twitter bootstrap carousel .on(slid) event that is fired after clicking a element that targets a particular slide, and an .on(slid) event that is fired after clicking a different element (close button). However once the second event occurs, it continues to fire even with the first on(slid) event. I thought preventDefault() would fix this but it doesn't. I even tried a more complete function (shown below, from [Herb Caudill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239663/herb-caudill)) to do this, but no go.

Using (this) to tie the scope of the event to the function didn't work. I am fairly new at this, so I am thinking there may be a fundamental concept here that I'm not grasping.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// Intended to prevent event bubble up or any usage after this is called.
eventCancel = function (e)
{
   if (!e)
     if (window.event) e = window.event;
     else return;
   if (e.cancelBubble != null) e.cancelBubble = true;
   if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
   if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
   if (window.event) e.returnValue = false;
   if (e.cancel != null) e.cancel = true;
}    

$('.recentContent').click(function(){
var $lastIndex = $('#splashCarousel .carousel-inner').children().last().getIndex();
$('#splashCarousel').carousel($lastIndex); //slide to specific index
$('#splashCarousel').carousel('pause');

$('#splashCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            alert("open");
    //do stuff
    return eventCancel(e);
})
});

$('.closeX').click(function(){

var $lastItem = $('#splashCarousel .carousel-inner').children().last();

$('#splashCarousel').carousel(0); 

$('#splashCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
        alert("close");
    //do other stuff
        return eventCancel(e);
})
});
```

and here's an even simpler fiddle trying preventDefault: http://jsfiddle.net/chardwick/a5Dpe/

What might I being doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I see some discussion elsewhere on SO about nesting events, both that they shouldn't be done, and that sometimes they have to. Either way I still seem to get multiple event firings. Using live() for event delegation looks promising. Still could use some feedback though, as it's all starting to muddle for me.